# datatype in the table should be Date/time or short tgext?

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I am desiging dataentryform in access . I made tables and the datatye of one field is Date/time but in property field in format I put `mm.\yyyy` to get month and year . how should I define input mask for it? I want to see --.----
when I enter data in form I can see calender beside this field but I have to choose day as well I dont want to choose day however the day that I chose doesnt save in table but I have to choose day aw well.

more explaination: I have 2 fields that should define as mm.yyyy .one field is (start of project example 01.2010) and the next field is end of project which also has the same format mm.yyyy (03.2015).
and later I want to get a query which shows duration of project ( end of project - start of project) . so I should also do calculation according to my data.
but I dont know what kind of data type should I define in the table for these two fields. at first I tried Date/Time . but I couldnt find suitable format. then I changed it to short text and I entered 00.0000 in input mask. 
what is the best solution because I have to calculate duration of project according to these two fields later? (in queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways around this. One is simply to allow the user to type freely in an unbound textbox, then validate/correct before updating.

Another is to have two/three juxtaposed textboxes for year-month(-day), then build the date value with *DateSerial(y, m, d)*.

in VBA, mm/yyyy alone can never form a date value, so must silently add a day somehow.

Input masks should be avoided as they are a prime hate object for users.

If you insist, you can get an idea how to handle this from my article:

[Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24659/Entering-ISO-formatted-date-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

It assumes the ISO sequence because year-month determines the possible day values.

**Addendum:**

Though decimal months is not an exact measure due to the varying day counts of the months, you will get pretty close with this function:

```
Public Function DecimalMonths( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    ByVal Date2 As Date) _
    As Double

    Dim Part1   As Double
    Dim Part2   As Double
    Dim Months  As Double
    Dim Days1   As Integer
    Dim Days2   As Integer

    Days1 = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date1), Month(Date1) + 1, 0))
    Days2 = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date2), Month(Date2) + 1, 0))

    Months = DateDiff("m", Date1, Date2)
    Part1 = (Day(Date1) - 1) / Days1
    Part2 = (Day(Date2) - 1) / Days2

    Months = Months - Part1 + Part2

    DecimalMonths = Months

End Function
```

Please note, that the count from 2017-04-15 to 2017-06-01 is 1.53

while it would be 1.5 from 2017-04-16 to 2017-06-01.

Comment: if I put two juxtaposed textboxes for year-month then what kind of datatype should I define for these two fields in the tables ?

Comment: That would be Integer, but it would be smarter to assemble the values with DateSerial. Takes a little coding convert, read, and write the values, so this is why this method is rarely used.

Comment: I understood the concept that you explained. I put date/time as a datatype for start and end of projects feilds. I have this senario . the complete date of starting and ending of the project (dd.mm.yyyy). and I want to know duration according to months. if my project starts from 15.04.2017 , and end is 01.06.2017 . is it possible to show months in decimal?
I tried DateDiff("m";[start];[end]) and it shows 2 as a result, I want to see 1.5 ?

Comment: I know with VBA it is possible. I am asking about function.

Comment: It's added to the answer.

Comment: .thanks , when I compiled it I am getting error in this line
Months = DateDiff(IntervalSetting("m", Date1, Date2))
Compile error: Sub or Function not defined.  in IntervalSetting part 
if I understood correctly I should chane it to DateAdd. 
and when I change it, I am getting another compile error : Argument not optional in Date diff  part of this line . why? I dont get its problem

Comment: Typo, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: sorry,I am new to access, I am not getting any error  but when I write it in control source of textbox it is not working. for examwhen I use DateDiff I am writing in control source 
DateDiff("m";[startDate];[endDate])
 and it shows months between two fields. (startDate and endDate are the name of my fields.in my system I should use ; instead of ,  ) 
 what do you write in controlsource or query for using this function?

Comment: It should be: `=DecimalMonths([startDate];[endDate])`.

Comment: thank you. fuction works properly in the form. but in the query if startdate is 01.03.2001 and enddate is 01.03.2017 (it means days both are 01) function works but if startdate is 01.02.1999 and enddate17.03.2017 (dd is different ) it shows ########. why? and in the form I am getting result.

Comment: The result will be `217.516129032258` so widen your field and textbox and/or set the _Format_ property to: _Fixed_

Comment: sorry another question.I wrote 

Nmonth:IIf(IsNull([startDate]) Or IsNull([endDate]);"";DecimalMonths([startDate];[endDate]))  
in query and form (unbound textbox in the form).  because it showes ?Type? or #Error if I dont enter startdate or end date. in the form I can set format property to fixed but in query, format shows nothing in dropdown list , I cannot limit  decimal digits to two. I put #,## in the format property  of query but result is nothing. do you have any idea ? in forms I can set fixed for format but I have problen in query.

Comment: Use: `IIf(IsNull([startDate]+[endDate]);Null;DecimalMonths([startDate];[endDate]))` and set the Format property of the textbox where you display the result.

Comment: I got error, it doesnt work for me in both query and form.

Comment: Then use: `IIf(IsNull([startDate]+[endDate]);Null;DecimalMonths(Nz([startD‌​ate];Date());Nz([endDate];Date())))`.

Comment: thanks, It doesnt work, error in qury is [undefined function 'Nz' in experssion]. actually I already used Nz in other parts and it works. I dont get a problem.

Comment: Then something else is going on. Nz has existed since Access 95.